# Using bootstrap, containing larger images to sit inside a smaller static div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My problem pretty much resides in image responsiveness within my middle row.

I'm using bootstrap 4, I've tried to use different classes like img-fluid and I actually have those rules in my `img` object on the style section.

I can't hard code image classes because this isn't for a website, this is for a display page. Users drag images into an area (which ultimately shows below in my row middle class with `#fullColumn`) so this is a static page display.Also, the images are saved via TinyMCE so they're always wrapped in

tags

The row top area is the header and always at the top of the page, while my row bottom section is always stuck to the bottom of the page, which is what I want. However, my `#fullColumn` area seems to always remain between the two as it should, just as I want, but if there's a HUGE image in that area then it breaks past the row top and/or row bottom and totally out of the `#fullColumn`. If I inspect it, the `#fullColumn` is still sitting between row top and row bottom  but the image is totally off the page.

Users are viewing this on a computer when they create the page, so they need to see that it fits the area, but it ultimately displays on 55-70" digital displays so in both of those cases I need any and all images in the `#fullColumn` area to just be centered and scaled accordingly. If the user puts a 2000x2000 pixel image into that area, I need it to sit centered and between the top and bottom rows either on their computer or on the display.

How can I just make sure that any and all images are scaled down enough and centered in my middle area?

[image]

```css
        html,
        body {
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        iframe{
          height:100% !important;
          width:100% !important;
        }

        .middle p{
          max-height:100%;
        }

        img {
          max-width: 100%; 
          height:auto;
          margin:0 auto;
        }
        #fullContent{
          display:flex;
          justify-content:center;
          align-items:center;
        }

        .fullContent > img{
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }

        #fullContent> img{
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .my-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 100vh;
          width:100vw;
        }

        .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
        .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
          background-color: #778899  ;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .my-container>.middle {
          flex-grow: 1;
          padding:30px;
          background-size: cover;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <div class="container-fluid my-container d-flex h-100">
  <div class="row top">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #929292;">
      <h3>Top Row</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
      <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
          <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">
                  <p>
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/2000">
                  <p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row bottom">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="row"><h2 style="margin: 40px;">Bottom Row</h2></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What does *"My problem pretty much resides in image responsiveness within my middle row"* mean? What is the problem and what should happen? Or what should be prevented from happening? Also, what does "accordingly" mean in *"scaled accordingly"*. Please define in clear the requirements/expectations.

Comment: I thought I had been pretty specific but maybe not. As the image shows, the problem is that the middle row/full content area (highlighted blue) is in the middle but the image isn't contained and breaks out of the area. When I say scaled accordingly, a huge image should be scaled down enough to fit within the middle area without breaking out or pushing it into the top or bottom row

Comment: Do you want the images to be contained in the parent (and see blank areas around the image when their ratio doesn't match) or to cover the parent (and crop the excess from the child), or do you want the parent to extend in height when necessary so that it matches the child's ratio?

Comment: I don't want the parent to extend, I want the parent (middle area) to always remain fixed between the top and bottom because this shows on a static display, there is no scrolling or anything. I want it to be contained and show blank areas though, not be cropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a few changes to your markup (you need to pay more attention to Bootstrap's grid system).
I might have done some other minor changes, but the bulk of what made it work is:

- applied `.d-flex` on the `<p>`
- added this CSS:

```css
.middle p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#fullContent img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.my-container .top.row, 
.my-container .row.bottom {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.middle p {
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#fullContent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fullContent>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#fullContent img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.my-container>.top [class^="col-"], .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
  background-color: #778899;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-container>.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.my-container .top.row, 
.my-container .row.bottom {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid my-container h-100">
  <div class="row top">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h3>Top Row</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row middle" id="middle">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
      <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%;">
        <p>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/4000x3500">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row bottom">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2 style="margin: 40px;">Bottom Row</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what can i add to the ```p``` tag in my CSS instead of using d-flex inline? The <p> tags get applied after the fact so I can't hard code a class to them

Comment: `display: flex` :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry, one more question: Is there a reason that if I have two images back to back within the ```<p>``` tags they stack on top of one another? Is there not a way to keep this functionality and have them side by side if that were the case?

Comment: `display: flex;` keeps them side by side if `flex-direction` is `row` (which it is, by default). To place them vertically, just change the `flex-direction` to `column`.